# How can I remove the product_id under the product description on the odoo (openerp) report_saleorder_document?

Tags: report, odoo

Please help ...

```
                <tr t-foreach="o.order_line" t-as="l">
                   <td>
                        <span t-field="l.name" />     
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

l.name include product_id .how can format ? i only want product  description

Product                 description 
[A123]ipad              [A123]ipad
                        16G,white

how can remove description "[A123]ipad" this product_name on my report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to overwrite name_get function of product.product object.

Here is example

```
class product_product(osv.osv):
    _inherit = 'product.product'

    def name_get(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        return_val = super(product_product, self).name_get(cr, uid, ids, context=context)
        res = []
        def _name_get(d):
            name = d.get('name','')
            if d.get('variants'):
                name = name + ' - %s' % (d['variants'],)
            return (d['id'], name)
        for product in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
            res.append((product.id, (product.name)))
        return res or return_val

product_product()
```

You have to make one customize module, and install it in your database. if you want to make change in directly product.py then you must do following changes in product.py of product module. replace following code

```
def _name_get(d):
name = d.get('name','')
code = d.get('default_code',False)
if code:
    name = '[%s] %s' % (code,name)
if d.get('variants'):
    name = name + ' - %s' % (d['variants'],)
return (d['id'], name)
```

with

```
def _name_get(d):
name = d.get('name','')
if d.get('variants'):
    name = name + ' - %s' % (d['variants'],)
return (d['id'], name)
```

I hope this solves your problem.

Thanks And Regards,

Yaseen Shareef